# How do I chain Wicket dropdown list events?

Tags: java, ajax, drop-down-menu, wicket

I'm trying to chain dropdown list events.

I have these data:

> Name auidi (a4{ 2006,2007,2008 } , a6{ 2006,2007,2009 } ,tt { 2005,2008,2010 }) 
>           ford  (crown {2009,2010} , escape{2008,2009})

When I select the name of the car I want models to be shown. Later I select the model, and I want years to be shown.

I've found this example: http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/nested/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.ChoicePage

But there, there are two dropdowns. There is also a map. Should I use a map in a map? If so, how can I set the model?

When the map is in the type `Map<String ,List<String >>`, the model is like:

```
IModel<List<? extends String>> makeChoices = 
    new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<? extends String>>() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public List<String> getObject() 
        { 
            Set<String> keys = modelsMap.keySet(); 
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(keys); 
            return list; 
        } 
    };
```

What if map is `Map<String,Map<String ,List<String >>>` ?

If I code

```
IModel<Map? extends String>> makeChoices = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<Map<? extends String>>()
```

My IDE warns me that it expects two arguments, and I don't know how to assign the values to the map in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case for 3 DropDownChoices you will need 3 models and all of them need to represent lists which provide choices. You need nested maps to simulate their relationships and later for retrieval, e.g:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> cars; //fill data
IModel<List<? extends String>> makeChoices = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<? extends String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> getObject() {
            Set<String> keys = cars.keySet();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(keys);
            return list;
        }
    };

IModel<List<? extends String>> modelChoices = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<? extends String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> getObject() {
            Map<String, List<String>> models = cars.get(selectedMake);
            if (models == null) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            } else {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(models.keySet());
                return list;
            }
        }
    };

 IModel<List<? extends String>> yearChoices = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<? extends String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> getObject() {
            Map<String, List<String>> models = cars.get(selectedMake);
            if (models == null) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            } else {
                return models.get(selectedModel);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: In your second model (modelChoices); in "models = Collections.emptyList()" line it gives incompatible type warning.Should it be collections.emptyMap();

Comment: And in 3rd model Netbeans warns me about same line.What about        final DropDownChoice<String> makes = new DropDownChoice<String>("makes",new PropertyModel<String>(this, "selectedMake"),makeChoices);

Comment: functions of 2nd and 3rd models has warning about missing return statement

Comment: I've revised the return statements and this is suggestion of how it should look like. You still need to manage internal state of selected options to provide options in lower levels. And there will be no empty maps, just empty lists.